# A weird unexpected behavior with history.push() from react-router-dom and connect() from react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

How is it going everyone:)

It looks like that the mapStateToProps function which is passed to the connect function as a first argument is called, before when the actual component is mounted or after the Redux store state changes by returning new plain object in a reducer.

However,I found some weird behavior between react-router-dom and react-redux packages.(probably I have lack of knowledge of using them). The problem that i faced is as mentioned above title, Push as the same route as you are currently in with history.push() just renders the actual component passed to the connect(). Not determined whether the component should be re-rendered or not from the mapStateToProps.

Here's the package's versions that i am using for this project.

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
```

Here's the code

```
 class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
     .
     .
     .
     .

     test = () => {
       //this.props.test();
       //Let's say you are currently in localhost:3000/
       this.props.history.push('/');
     };

     render() {
       console.log('[SomeComponent] is rendered');

       <button onClick={this.test}>test</button>
     }

 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log('mapStateToProps is called in [SomeComponent]');

   return {
     someValue: state.someValue
   };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    test: () => dispatch({ type: 'test' }),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

and I know that when this.props.test() which is commented above and also action dispatching is invoked instead of this.props.history.push('/') in test method, a reducer function takes that flow and there is no match with the action.type.test so it returns the same reference object as before. Therefore the mapStateToProps function for subscribing to Redux store change is not going be fired.

I am trying to understand and search this behavior all day but it was hard to find the answer that i wanted.

I would really appreciate that if you guys help with this problem or with my poor knowledge.

Thank you:) and sorry for my poor English:(

Comment: history.push('/') basically just adds an entry into your browser history. If you are at the same page, then the page is not actually reloaded, and your component is not remounted.

Comment: thank you for your comment:) but every time i click the button, I see the log says '[SomeComponent] is rendered' which means somehow this component was re-rendered by some parent component or <Route> component which imports actually the result of connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent) so I thought re-rendering cycle should be through the mapStateToProps which determines if the actual component should re-renders or not. But i don't see the log says 'mapStateToProps is called in [SomeComponent]'.